# how to set application waiting or busy using vb.net?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, windows

I just trying to make a adobe reader to be busy until wpf vb operation is completed.

I use

```
 AppActivate(File_Name + " - Adobe Reader")
```

To get the focus of the adobe reader open file. and until i do the calculation and get the user data from the user i want the adobe reader active file to be busy.

Please someone help me with this...

Comment: Depends to you want to block the entire application or just change the cursor? What is your desired effect to make it look like its busy?

Comment: block the entire application

Comment: You could just open the file in the background (invisible).Perform your calculation and after your calculation is completed then you focus it.

Comment: I have to ask the user to give the value based on which i am doing my calculation. At the time the user should not be able to access the app.

Comment: Yes but he isn't supposed to enter the value in adobe, is he? Otherwise i am afraid there isn't a quick fix to be offered.

Comment: yes he can enter a value on a wpf application window which opens using adobe reader js, But not on the Adobe reader page...